# google services has stopped wont stop long enough for me to fix the problem cant even get into my settings

Tags: google-play-store

google services keeps looping gives me no time to fix due to it just keeps forcing me back to same looping message cant even get into my settings for long enough to repair because it just throws me back to the same looping error screen

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also and here is how I got past it. I also used this to recover my friends phone.
The high frequency of the app failures makes it very hard to access the settings menu and make your selections. Even so, tap the failure messages to get them to close. In between tap or try pulling the settings menu down from the top of the screen. After several tries it seemed there was very slight pause in the failure cascade. I used that slight pause to make my settings menu selections. Either way, after pulling down the settings menu I selected Back up / Reset. You have to keep closing the failure messages and try flicking the menu down to the option you want but it is possible if you are quick and persistent. I just factory reset mine, but I've read suggestions to clear the caches of several apps central to the phone's operation. Tomorrow I have another to do and I'll try clearing caches then return to update on how that worked.  Best of luck.